# Entity Framework Core deleting migrations?

Tags: entity-framework

I deleted all my migrations

I deleted my ModelSnapshot.cs

I deleted my database

I now run `Add-Migration Init`

I would expect a new migration containing all my models being created and applied in that single migration.

Instead i see the latest changes to the model.

Its clear there is some magic caching going on somewhere.
Where is this magic cache and how do I delete it?

Or do i have to delete the entire project and start over copying over my EF models?

Comment: Please check for **Migrations** folder in your project. You have to delete generated migrations also.

Comment: @Karan i've deleted the entire migration folder using file explorere. Its removed from disk. Not just from Visual Studio.